# After an action is dispatched part of my redux state is reset

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm facing a really weird issue here. It seems like that when an action is being dispatched part of my state is being reset. I can't understand the reason since my app is constructed by the same way. I've also use `persistStore` for this reason. This is a major issue.

Comment: can you paste some of your code from reducers ? 
Most probably you are returning empty state for the cases where it is going to default statement. Or you must be overriding few of the keys of  the state objects.

Comment: It was en error with the default hadling...thanks a lot :)